Determine p-value for specificity between two algorithms using R
In R, I have a dataframe that has looks like this (2000+ rows):
Sample  AlgoA   AlgoB
A   FP  TP
B   TN  TN
C   TP  TP
D   FN  TP
E   FP  FP
F   TN  TN
G   TP  TP

The TN/TP etc is coming by comparing the algo to a truth set.
I've generated spec/sense values by doing the usual calculations, and also generated my 95% CIs.
I just need to now see if there's a statistical difference between the two groups. what should I do in this case? AlgoA and AlgoB are totally unrelated, just two different lab methods.
